Failing to download node js version in azure devops ubuntu self hosted agent
I am using the azure vmss machine as self hosted agent which gets provisioned during the pipeline execution. I am running the below code. However it gets failed and throws the error message. Kindly suggest how can i fix the below code. Just to add, it works fine if i use windows agent but fails when i use Ubuntu.
Error Message:

##[error]Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established

Pipeline code:
  stages:  
    - stage: "BuildStage"
      displayName: "Build Stage"
      jobs:
        - job: "BuildJob"
          displayName: "BuildJob"
          steps:
            - task: NodeTool@0
              inputs:
                #versionSource: 'spec'
                versionSpec: '18.x'
              displayName: "setting node version"
        
            - script: |
                npm install
              displayName: "Prepare binaries"
    
            - script: |
                npm run build
              displayName: "Building the project"
    
            - task: ArchiveFiles@2
              displayName: "Archiving the files"
              inputs:
                rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
                includeRootFolder: false
                archiveType: 'zip'
                archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
                replaceExistingArchive: true
              
            - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
              displayName: publishing pipeline artifacts
              inputs:
                PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
                ArtifactName: 'drop'
                publishLocation: 'Container'


Which task is failing?

@RuiJarimba its NodeTool@0

Run the pipeline with system.debug=true and share the log outputs from the NodeTool@0 task.

Was your VMSS resource behind a firewall or configured with VPN? Have you tested to download the package https://nodejs.org/dist/v18.20.2/node-v18.20.2-linux-x64.tar.gz on one of the VMSS instances and does it work?

@AlvinZhao-MSFT thanks for the comment, this was the problem it was behind the firewall.

Hi @SharatBhaskar, Thanks for the update. May I know if it is possible to add the URLhttps://nodejs.org to the firewall whitelist and if the problem can be resolved this way?

Hi @SharatBhaskar, May I know if the answer below to configure firewall could help resolve your issue? Could you please let us know the latest status or your solution to fix the error? Thx.

Based on the discussion, the affected VMSS resource was behind the firewall, which may have caused failure in downloading of the nodejs packages from https://nodejs.org/.
Please make sure all the required network access by the pipeline steps is added into the whitelist of your firewall before running those steps in pipeline.
